# Call a specific method using Restlet framework

Tags: java, rest, restlet

I'm using [Restlet library](http://restlet.org/) and I would like to know if it is possible to call a specific method of a class when accessing through a URL.

Right now I have something like this:

```
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());  

    router.attach("/monitor", Monitor.class);
}
```

Which calls the `Monitor` class when accessing to `/monitor/` by URL. 
I would like to be able to do things like this:

```
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());      

    router.attach("/monitor/name", Monitor.getName());
    router.attach("/monitor/description", Monitor.getDescription());
}
```

Is this possible with Restlet framework?
Right now the workaround I found was by using GET parameters and using conditions on the `represent` method:

```
public StringRepresentation represent() {
    String type= getQuery().getValues("type");

    if(type.equals("getName")){
        this.getName();
    }
    if(type.equals("getDescription")){
        this.getDescription();
    }    
}
```

But it doesn't sound like the way to do it.

Comment: the standard JAX-RS style allow this kind of configuration through annotation.. http://www.techferry.com/articles/RESTful-web-services-JAX-RS-annotations.html.  Restlet seems to have JAX-RS support extension http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.2/extensions/jax-rs .. combining the information in the two URLs might point to a possible solution?

Comment: Based on the basic concept /monitor/name and /monitor/description are resources, so you should use different classes for them. Instead of trying invoke different methods, I suggest to use one resource for Monitor (/monitor) and filter the output with query parameters like: /monitor?filter=name and /monitor?filter=description

Comment: `monitor/name` would just return an string as well as `monitor/description` so they shouldn't be classes. They are just properties of a class returned by a public method.

Comment: If there is an answer to this I'd like to know it.  Sometimes it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is the best way to validate REST guidelines.
So, unless you convert name and description to be resources leave it this way.